# Geolocalized image over mapview in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, android-mapview

my question is the following: how can I do to set a fixed geolocalized image over a mapview in a way that the zoom over the map is also applied over the image. I search the same behaviour like, for example, this page: http://www.glerl.noaa.gov/res/glcfs/kml/glcfsmap.php.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [overlay tiler project](https://code.google.com/p/overlay-tiler/)?  I presume you want to upload an image, georeference it, and then have it load as tiles on the map.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm sorry if I'm not clear, but I want to do that in Android (I've updated the title of the post for more clearly). But it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I need that the image keeps fixed. If I do a zoom, I need that the image gets the zoom too.